# AngularJs: XML File is Not Downloading in Firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cross-browser

I'm new in AngularJS as well as in UI. I'm trying to download XML file. Which is working fine in Google Chrome but in Mozilla Firefox it is not able to download. My JS function is:

```
response.success(function(data){
     var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "application/xml"});
     var downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
     downloadLink.attr('href',window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
     downloadLink.attr('download', "file.xml");
     downloadLink[0].click();
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with other way and Now It's working in Firefox-

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
     var blob = new Blob([data], {
       type: 'text/xml'
     });
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
     element.href = url;
     element.setAttribute('download', 'acl.xml');
     document.body.appendChild(element); 
     element.click();
```

Comment: Let me ask, that was because an issue with Content-Type?